# How to fix no image?

Tags: image, codeigniter, upload

I tried some codes as below and got an error message

> Error Number: 1048
>   Column brand_logo cannot be null
>   INSERT INTO tbl_brand (brand_name, brand_logo) VALUES ('Incoe', NULL)"

Please help me find out error (sorry for my poor English)

This is Model:

```
public function add_brand_model($brand_logo){
    $data['brand_name'] = $this->input->post('brand_name',true);
    $data['brand_logo'] = $brand_logo;
    $this->db->insert('tbl_brand',$data);
}
```

view:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Upload Brand Logo</label>
   <input type="file" name="brand_logo">
</div>
```

and Controller:

```
public function add_brand_form(){
    $data['main_content'] = $this->load->view('back/add_brand','',true);
    $this->load->view('back/adminpanel',$data);
}
public function save_brand(){
    $brand_logo= $this->upload_brand_logo();
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('brand_name','Brand Name','required|min_length[2]');
    if($this->form_validation->run()){
        $this->BrandModel->add_brand_model($brand_logo);
        $this->session->set_flashdata("flsh_msg","<font class='success'>Brand Added Successfully</font>");
           redirect('brand-list');
    }else{
        $this->add_brand_form();
    }
}
private function upload_brand_logo(){
    $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'png|gif|jpg|jpeg';
    $config['max_size']             = 1000;//kb
    $config['max_width']            = 1024;
    $config['max_height']           = 768;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if($this->upload->do_upload('brand_logo')){
        $data = $this->upload->data();
        $image_path = "uploads/$data[file_name]";
        return $image_path;
    }else{
          $error =  $this->upload->display_errors();
        $this->session->set_userdata('error_image',$error);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if($this->upload->do_upload('brand_logo')){
    $data = $this->upload->data();
    $image_path = "uploads/".$data[file_name]; //Change
    return $image_path;
}else{
    $error =  $this->upload->display_errors();
    $this->session->set_userdata('error_image',$error);
    return false; //New addition
}
```

OR

```
$image_path = '';
if($this->upload->do_upload('brand_logo')){
    $data = $this->upload->data();
    $image_path = "uploads/".$data[file_name]; //Change
}else{
    $error =  $this->upload->display_errors();
    $this->session->set_userdata('error_image',$error);
}
return $image_path; //return here only one time
```